# LC Oscillator and relativity

Tags: general-relativity, harmonic-oscillator

There are two identical LC oscillators with electronic counters attached indicating how many times they have oscillated (from the time they are turned on).
They are turned on simultaneously and one is kept on earth and other one is hurled to outer space at very large speeds on a rocket and brought back to earth after traveling several million miles. Does relativity say they will show two different counts ? (One traveled will show less than the one on earth)

Comment: *All* tpyes of clocks---no matter how they work aside from a presumption that they actually measure time---will exhibit time dilation because time dilation is a real effect.

Comment: Does it mean the relativity affects the physical properties of the timing elements (L,C Xtals etc) in such a way that time dilation happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special Relativity "says" that a clock with a straight worldline through two events records a larger elapsed time between the events than a clock with any other worldline through the same two events thus, the "stay at home" LC oscillator shows the most counts.

Comment: Does it mean that LC oscillator frequency equation has a "relativity component" which is ignored for earthly purposes ? Or does L or C change with speed ?

Comment: @Jean, the LC oscillator equation comes from ideal circuit theory which is based on a number of simplifying assumptions which are not compatible with a relativistic system.  Further, one of the LC oscillators experiences enormous acceleration at least twice.  I haven't thought through this interesting question but, I can imagine that length contraction would factor into the calculation of the L and C of a moving inductor and capacitor respectively.

Comment: @Jean, my suspicion seems to be correct:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_electromagnetism#Uniform_electric_field_.E2.80.94_simple_analysis  Now, I haven't perused this Wiki article but, on the face of it, it seems reasonable that there is some relativistic correction to moving capacitors and inductors.